# Consulta SAP Query

Tags: sap

quiero consultar cual es mi error, que  no es de sintaxis, sino de logica en la consulta, estoy intentando generar un informe donde se muestre en detalle los Articulos que se cotizaron, y van a ser utilizados en un trabajo de servicio autos. 
( EJ: CAMBIO DE ACEITE, ALINEACION, ETC ) 
El query es para SAP BO.

Lo que sucede es que me duplica los campos, y tampoco realiza el filtro de la fecha que le configure (Selecciono una fecha y aun asi me trae todas las demas fechas igual)

Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
QUERY= 

SELECT T0."CreateDate", T0."U_BoxPatent", T1."ItemCode", T0."U_Branch", T0."U_EstadoOT", T2."draftKey", T1."ItemCode",T1."U_ArtEst", T0."U_EstRec", T1."DocEntry" 

FROM "ODBC"."@EXX_ORDT"  T0 , QUT1 T1 INNER JOIN OQUT T2 ON T1."DocEntry" = T2."DocEntry" 

WHERE T0."U_Branch" IS NOT NULL
AND
 T0."U_EstRec" =  '[%1]'
OR
T0."CreateDate" between '[%2]' AND '[%3]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta agregando un `INNER JOIN` a la tabla principal con una de las secundarias ya que en el original no existe tal relacion de esta forma:

```
FROM "ODBC"."@EXX_ORDT"  T0 INNER JOIN OQUT T2 ON T0.campo = T2.campo
OQUT T2 INNER JOIN QUT T1 ON T2."DocEntry" = T1."DocEntry"
```

ademas agregale el `DISTINCT` a tu seleccion:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T0."CreateDate", T0."U_BoxPatent", T1."ItemCode", T0."U_Branch", T0."U_EstadoOT", T2."draftKey",T1."ItemCode",T1."U_ArtEst", T0."U_EstRec", T1."DocEntry"
```

Saludos